# How to work with rich join tables in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, join

I am stuck struggling with rich join tables in Rails 5 and need help getting on track.  The app I'm writing will help me track which of our company's suppliers carry which brands of products.  Because I also need to track whether each supplier is authorized or unauthorized for each of the brands they sell, and whether they carry those brands in stock, I thought the best approach was to use a join table and store the attributes there.  In other words:

```
Suppliers <---> Lines <---> Brands
```

Beyond the foreign key references for a `Supplier` and a `Brand`, the `Line` record also has two boolean attributes: `.is_authorized` and `.carries_stock`.

My models:

**/models/supplier.rb**

```
class Supplier < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :lines, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :brands, :through => :lines

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :lines
end
```

**/models/brand.rb**

```
class Brand < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :lines, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :suppliers, :through => :lines
end
```

**/models/line.rb**

```
class Line < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :supplier
  belongs_to :brand

  validates_presence_of :supplier
  validates_presence_of :brand
end
```

I've been able to set up the controller and supplier edit form to allow creating records in the `Lines` table, but have no clue how to allow the users to edit the `.is_authorized` and `.carries_stock` attributes.  I have been able to get the create/edit supplier form to work by adding the following snippet:

**/views/suppliers/_form.html.erb**

```
  <h4>Brands</h4>
  <%= form.collection_check_boxes(:brand_ids, Brand.all, :id, :name) do |b| %>
    <%= b.label class:"label-checkbox" do%>
      <%= b.check_box + b.text%>
    <%end%>
    <br />
  <% end %>
```

[The form looks like this now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8t9Gq.png) but doesn't allow me to edit the rich attributes `.is_authorized` and `.carries_stock`.  I'd like the form [to look something more like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sexxh.png).  Where do I go from here?

Thanks!!!